# Unable to read inner array property from Mongo collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to read a property from array of object in C# code using Mongo driver but it's not working. Example of Json document.

```js
{
    _id:""
        EmpId: 100
       roles: [
      {
            roleId:1,
            roleName:"test"
          },
      {
            roleId:2,
            roleName:"test2"
          }
       ]

}
```

C# code

```js
 var data = _db.GetCollection<Employee>(collection).Aggregate().Unwind<Employee>("roles");

 var output1= data.Project(i=> new { roleId= i.roleId }).ToList();
```

Code is throwing error

```js
Cannot deserialize a 'List<roles>' from BsonType 'Document'.
```

Comment: try to rename `Roles` to `roles`.

Comment: tried it didn't work.